# How can I take the data in this service from an HTTP get call?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http

I have a little issue from an Angular app to get a code from my own server.

I´ve built up a little Spotify App for learning more about Angular 10 and have a little backend that I only use for get the Bearer code to call the Spotify API, but the fact is that in my Angular front I can´t save the code.

Tis is my service call code to the back:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SpotifyService {

  token: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Spotify service ready');
    this.getAccesToken().subscribe(data => this.token = data['access_token']);
   }

   getAccesToken(){
      return this.http.get(environment.server + `${environment.client_id}/${environment.client_secret}`)
     .pipe(
       map(res => res)
     );
   }

   getQuery(query: any){
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
    });
     const url = `https://api.spotify.com/v1/${query}`;

     return this.http.get(url, {headers});
   }
```

I´ve checked the recibed data and I get the request perfectly, but can´t save the data of the suscriber into a variable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you give your component's code where you're calling the getAccesToken method?

Comment: @SachinLahiruPathirana I´m not calling the method in a Component, I´m trying to keep it in the own Service and use it only there

Comment: @B2DAW Well, then post that part. Whatever is subscribing to getQuery() and trying to set your variable.

Comment: Are you not able to save the token returned by getAccessToken method?

Comment: @nharrer I´ve tried it, but all time ```undefined```

Comment: @NikhilWalvekar I try, but anything I´ve tried to save in a variable, is all time ```undefined```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your component code looks like below, you can make some adjustments and try it.

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {

  spotifyData;
  user;
  token;
  constructor(private spotifyService: SpotifyService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    console.log(this.user);
    this.token = this.user.token;
    this.getSpotifyData();
  }

  getSpotifyData() {
    this.spotifyService.getQuery(this.user, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.token) }).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res) {
        spotifyData = res;
      } else {
        spotifyData = []
      }
    });
  }
```